# How to pad a numeric string with zeros to the right in Python?

Tags: python, string

Python strings have a method called `zfill` that allows to pad a numeric string with zeros to the left.

```
In : str(190).zfill(8)
Out: '00000190'
```

How can I make the pad to be on the right ?

Comment: You could always convert the string to an integer, multiply by 10**(num-length), and convert back to string.

Answer (score 53, accepted):

See [Format Specification Mini-Language](https://docs.python.org/3/library/string.html#format-specification-mini-language):

```
In [1]: '{:<08d}'.format(190)
Out[1]: '19000000'

In [2]: '{:>08d}'.format(190)
Out[2]: '00000190'
```

---

This also works with the [Formatted String Literals](https://docs.python.org/3/tutorial/inputoutput.html#formatted-string-literals), or ***f-strings*** for short (*New in version 3.6*):

```
In [1]: f'{190:<08d}'
Out[1]: '19000000'

In [2]: f'{190:>08d}'
Out[2]: '00000190'
```

Comment: If your input is a string and you get *"Unknown format code 'd' for object of type 'str'"*, you may use `"{:<08s}"`.

Comment: shorter notation example: `f'{3:>02d}'` yields 03, `f'{3:<02d}'` yields 30

Answer (score 58):

As maybe a alternative more portable [1] and efficient [2], actually you can just use [str.ljust](https://mail.python.org/pipermail/python-list/2008-August/505557.html).

```
In [2]: '190'.ljust(8, '0')
Out[2]: '19000000'

In [3]: str.ljust?
Docstring:
S.ljust(width[, fillchar]) -> str

Return S left-justified in a Unicode string of length width. Padding is
done using the specified fill character (default is a space).
Type:      method_descriptor
```

[1] format is not present on old python versions. format specifier was added since Python 3.0 (see [PEP 3101](https://www.python.org/dev/peps/pep-3101/)) and Python 2.6.

[2] reverse twice is an expensive operation.

Comment: With [2] ... Do you mean that the double reverse is slower right ?

Comment: Yes, double reverse is slower. The [2] phrase has a typo. I meant *expensive* operation, not *expansive*. I'll fix that.

Answer (score 15):

Hint: The string can be inverted twice: before and after using the `zfill` method:

```
In : acc = '991000'

In : acc[::-1].zfill(9)[::-1]
Out: '991000000'
```

Or even more easier:

```
In : acc.ljust(9, '0')
Out: '991000000'
```

Comment: Funny I never noticed ljust and rjust existed! Thanks for this!!!

Answer (score -1):

Here is a good way to do string padding :

```
def generate_fixed_length_string(input_string, target_length=5, fill_char='0'):
  """
  Pads a string with leading characters to reach a fixed length.

  Args:
      input_string (str): The input string to pad.
      target_length (int, optional): The desired length of the padded string. Defaults to 5.
      fill_char (str, optional): The character to use for padding. Defaults to '0'.

  Returns:
      str: The padded string.

  Raises:
      ValueError: If target_length is not positive or if the resulting string length would exceed the maximum supported length.
  """

  if target_length <= 0:
    raise ValueError("target_length must be a positive integer")

  padding_length = target_length - len(input_string)
  if padding_length < 0:
    raise ValueError("Input string is already longer than the target length")

  return fill_char * padding_length + input_string
```