# How do I force a python Decimal to have atleast two decimals?

Tags: python, decimal

I would need to format a python Decimal object to have atleast two decimals, but no more than 5. Is there a reliable way to do this?
Examples:

```
1.6 --> 1.60
1.678 --> 1.678
1.98765 --> 1.98765
```

If there are more than two decimals, it is vital that it does not get truncated to only two decimals.

Comment: Decimals as numbers are the same representation. You can transform them into string and use string formatting operations to achieve this. For that, you can use the following question: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/40999973/how-to-pad-a-numeric-string-with-zeros-to-the-right-in-python

Comment: @AlexanderSantos I am sorry, but the question I asked is not a duplicate, as truncation is not an option.

Comment: It looks to me like there are two parts to this question - one, determining the correct number of digits and two, quantizing the values to that number of digits. The second is answered by the accepted answer on the marked duplicate (use the `quantize()` method - there are multiple ways to construct a `decimal.Decimal` value of the correct exponent to use as the `quantize()` arg) but the first is not.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It looks to me like there are two parts to this question - one, determining the correct number of digits and two, quantizing the values to that number of digits.

To do the first, I would get the current exponent using the `as_tuple()` method. Unless I'm overlooking something simpler.

```
>>> import decimal
>>> d = decimal.Decimal("1.678")
>>> d.as_tuple().exponent
-3

>>> d2 = decimal.Decimal("1.6")
>>> d2.as_tuple().exponent
-1
```

So from that you can compute the desired exponent:

```
MAX_EXPONENT = -2
MIN_EXPONENT = -5
def desired_exponent(d):
    current_exponent = d.as_tuple().exponent
    return min(MAX_EXPONENT, max(MIN_EXPONENT, current_exponent))
```

The second is answered by [the accepted answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/1995846/4518341) on the marked duplicate - use the quantize() method. You'll need to construct a `Decimal` value with the desired exponent you can provide as the argument to `quantize()`. There are multiple ways to do that, but two simple ones are exponentiating `decimal.Decimal("10")` or using the `tuple` constructor for `decimal.Decimal()`.

```
>>> quant_arg = decimal.Decimal("10") ** -2
>>> decimal.Decimal("1.6").quantize(quant_arg)
Decimal('1.60')
```

Or:

```
>>> quant_arg = decimal.Decimal((0, (), -2))
>>> decimal.Decimal("1.6").quantize(quant_arg)
Decimal('1.60')
```

I used -2 as a literal there, you'd want to use the calculated value of `desired_exponent`.

There are multiple ways to organize this code, I think the parts that are not obvious are a) accessing the current exponent of a decimal value and b) some of the ways of constructing an arg for `quantize()`. And this is all assuming you need the actual decimal objects, and aren't just outputting them - if this is a question just about output formatting re-quantizing is probably overkill.

Comment: Is quantize a costly operation? Right now my main concern is stability and maintainability, but I am open to suggestions. It would be good if python had this built-in. I have made a solution now based on your suggestions.

Comment: It creates a new `decimal.Decimal` object, so it's not too bad but there's some data copying. I wouldn't let that stop me unless I were doing this for extremely large numbers of objects, personally - recommending formatting over quantizing if you're only using this for output formatting is just trying to choose the right level to change things - like using a truncating format string instead of `int()` if I wanted just the integer part of a float.

Answer (score 0):

Here is the code I use now:

```
def unitAmount(value):
    """Format a Decimal to match -?[0-9]{1,15}(,[0-9]{2,5})?
    Minimum two decimals, max 5.
    """
    decimals = value.as_tuple().exponent
    if decimals == -1:  # For values like 1.6 --> 1.60
        value = value.quantize(Decimal('1.00'))
    elif decimals < -5:  # For values like 1.1234567.. --> 1.12345
        value = value.quantize(Decimal('1.00000'))
    return value
```

Comment: Do you ever have input that might have an exponent of 0 or higher, eg `value = decimal.Decimal("10")`? I might check `if decimals >= -1:` personally.

Comment: The function is used for an invoicing-software and specifies the unit price. For some reason the standard allows integers, but not decimals with only one decimal. A comma is used as the decimal point.