# Adding a zero to the end of the string value without changing the column type

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe

I have string column in my `df` table, like this below:

```
d = {'col1': ['1.2', '3.4', '1.99', '0.14', '2.9', '', '2.3']}
df = pd.DataFrame(data=d)
df
```

[image]

I would like to convert this column, so that all values ​​contain two decimal places, but **without changing the type of this column to numeric type**.

Expected output - a string column with values:

[image]

I am a little new to Python, I tried padding 0 [How to pad a numeric string with zeros to the right in Python?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/40999973/how-to-pad-a-numeric-string-with-zeros-to-the-right-in-python/46021306) depending on the length of the value in the column, but it actually didn't work.

Do you have idea how to handle it?

Comment: "Didn't work" is not a problem description...

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use [`str.ljust`](https://pandas.pydata.org/docs/reference/api/pandas.Series.str.ljust.html):

```
df['col1'] = df['col1'].str.ljust(4, '0')
```

output:

```
   col1
0  1.20
1  3.40
2  1.99
3  0.14
4  2.90
5  2.30
```

To leave empty rows intact:

```
df['col1'] = df['col1'].mask(df['col1'].astype(bool), df['col1'].str.ljust(4, '0'))
```

output:

```
   col1
0  1.20
1  3.40
2  1.99
3  0.14
4  2.90
5      
6  2.30
```

NB. to get the max string length: `df['col1'].str.len().max()` -> `4`

Answer (score 1):

Like this:

```
df['col1'] = df['col1'].astype(float).map('{:,.2f}'.format).astype(str)
```

If you have '' in this column you better replace them before to '0'.

Comment: I would like to convert this column, so that all values ​​contain two decimal places, but without changing the type of this column to numeric type.

Comment: I am changing it back at the end of the process

Comment: @gtomer thanks, but I got error: "could not convert string to float:"

Comment: If you have '' in this column you better replace them before to '0'.

Comment: If I do so, according to your code in the output in the place I will get "0.00". And I expect not to change "  :(

Answer (score 0):

This one will work no matter how many columns are in your dictionary.
Try this:

```py
d = {'col1': ['1.2', '3.4', '1.99', '0.14', '2.9' '', '2.3']}
for x in d:
  for y in range(0,len(d[x])):
    d[x][y]=d[x][y].ljust(4,"0")
print(d)
```

Answer (score 0):

You can easily use the `round` or `format` function. In your specific case, using `format`, you can write something like this:

```
d = ['1.2', '3.4', '1.99', '0.14', '2.9', '', '2.3']
for i in range(len(d)):
     if d[i] == '':
          d[i] = '0'    
     d[i] = "{:.2f}".format(float(d[i]))
print ('col1', d)
```

output:

```
'col1', ['1.20', '3.40', '1.99', '0.14', '2.90', '0.00', '2.30']
```